# Vuex - ...mapActions call from template: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, store, vuex

I'm new to Vue, i'm just trying to figure out how it is working.
I use router and i have a parent and a child element.
In the child, i have this simple HTML element in the child component:
`<button @click="consoleLog">consoleLog</button>`

The store at the main.js have this action:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    userName: undefined,
    password: undefined,
    authenticated: false
},
mutations: {
    changeUserNameMutation(state, userName) {
        state.userName = userName;
    },
    changePasswordMutation(state, password) {
        state.password = password;
        Vue.axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = password;
    },
    changeAuthenticatedMutation(state, isAuthenticated) {
        state.authenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }
},
actions: {
    changeUserName({ commit }, userName) {
        commit('changeUserNameMutation', userName);
    },
    changePassword({ commit }, password) {
        commit('changePasswordMutation', password);
        Vue.axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = password;
    },
    changeAuthenticated({ commit }, isAuthenticated) {
        commit('changeAuthenticatedMutation', isAuthenticated);
    },
    consoleLog({ commit }) {
        console.log('sad');
    }
}
```

Nothing more really in the main.js, just the new Vue call, Vue.use() calls and the imports.

In the child component, i have this actions:

```
methods: {
    changeUserName(userName) {
        store.dispatch('changeUserName', userName);
    },
    changePassword(password) {
        store.dispatch('changePassword', password);
    },
    login() {
        this.axios.get('http://localhost:3050/admin/login')
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    },
    ...mapActions(['consoleLog'])
}
```

The first 2 dispatch working, but when i hit the consoleLog method, it's says:
`Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined at VueComponent.mappedAction`

I've tried all other way to call ...mapActions(), but not working this way somehow for me.
(this is my first day in Vue, trying how it's working)

Comment: Can you please provide more code. How are you configuring your Store?
Why do you call `store.dispatch` instead of `this.$store.dispatch`?

Comment: In `consoleLog` you reference commit which is used for mutations not actions. So perhaps you want `...mapMutations(['consoleLog])`? Ref [Committing Mutations in Components](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components)

Comment: To be honest i don't know why i'm calling store instead of this.$store, the basic examples showed this way to do it. Actually i want to call an action from a child component with the mapActions way, thats what i try to achieve. Code updated!